# Android Studio build error - compileDebugJavaWithJavac task (current target is 1.8) and kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin task (current target is 17)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Getting the following build error in Android Studio

```
compileDebugJavaWithJavac task (current target is 1.8) and kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same java version
```

during the kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin step of project build in Android Studio

Am on Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Canary 3

Full stack trace below

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.validateKotlinAndJavaHasSameTargetCompatibility(Tasks.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(Tasks.kt:722)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin_common(Tasks.kt:530)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:450)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:417)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.execute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
```

Comment: Can you share your app build.gradle file? I believe it is related with the java version used in your gradle and the java version used by your machine. Seems that you are using Java 17 in your machine and java 1.8 in your project.

Comment: Had a similar issue, @rockar06 's suggestion helped: I was using JDK 17, switching to the JDK bundled with Android Studio (it is currently version 11) solved the issue

Comment: @Eyjafl when you say "switching to the JDK bundled with Android Studio" what do you mean?  I'm using the bundled JDK in the gradle settings (17.0.6 in this case) but I still get the failures.  Only when I set the compile options per https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480587/3934023 does this work for me...

Comment: @Zach I mean the JDK installed inAndroid Studio itself (`.../Android/Android Studio/jbr`). In my case (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2) the bundled JDK is 11.0.15.

Comment: Ah, okay.  You are using Electric Eel.  I was running into this issue on Giraffe (which changed to use Java 17 as the bundled version) which is why I was confused about this.  Thanks for clarifying. I'll need to double check my default setup as well, since I use the bundled version always... but maybe it's a different bug for Giraffe users still

Comment: @rockar06 Most java developer machines have at least a dozen jdks installed in various places, so saying "the java version used by your machine" isn't very specific.

Comment: FWIW, I used this problem to switch over to using the build.grade.kts setup from the official Crane example code https://github.com/android/compose-samples and the problem went away.  That's a huge change for an existing large project though.

Answer (score 89):

I'm using **Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1**

I'm getting similar error. These settings worked for me.

`build.gradle(:project)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

`build.gradle(:app)`

```
...
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
...
```

Gradle Projects Settings

[image]

Comment: The last change (setting the GRADLEW JDK to jbr 1.7) is the only thing that worked for me...

Comment: Not really a solution as all you are doing is dowgrading to 1.7

Comment: Nope. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Check @volard's answer before you downgrade. Rather, you should upgrade your Gradle JDK to (at least) 18. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76394599/654870

Answer (score 25):

You can set it up in gradle (kts) file:

```
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

Comment: Nice!
FYI, the trick is, this configuration has to be applied to all the modules. The issue exists even when we miss any one of the module :)

Comment: @PrasannaNarshim correct, forgot to mention ;), thanks

Answer (score 18):

#### I'm using **Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Canary 6**

I'm getting the similar error. And I've solved it just like [@Halil Ozel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7799462/halil-ozel) did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76121852/12541622). Someone commented his answer as *"just downgrading to 1.7"*, but actually you're not restricted to setup a higher version.

#### For example, I have following settings

- `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`

**Gradle**: Wrapper 
**Gradle JDK**: corretto-18 Amazon Corretto version 18.0.2 (downloaded manually inside Android Studio) 
[image: Screenshot representing the setting]

- `build.gradle.kts (:app)`

```
...

android {
   defaultConfig {...}
   buildTypes {...}

   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "18"
    }
...

}
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I was able to correct that problem with this configuration:

**build.gradle:Project**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}
```

**build.gradle:app**

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

kotlinOptions {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

// For use with compose add the line below as well
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

**Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2**

This setting works for me:

**buid.gradle(Project)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
  
}
```

**buid.gradle(app)**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '18'
}
```

**Settings:**
**Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

open the **build.gradle(Project: DemoEx)** and paste the below code below plugins block. You can avoid plugins block given below.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
```

also change ***build.gradle(Module: DemoEx)***

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This settings worked for me

```
compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error while trying to connect dagger 2.42

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

And change version to 2.44.2

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.44.2'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution offered by Paul H. Vargas worked for me.

Instead of downgrade to 17 this made the problematic task to change it's target to the same version.

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting the same version in compileOptions and kotlinOptions. This is how my code looks like:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: jvmTarget needs to be a String

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested in using the latest **JVM toolchain** approach:

1. You must use `AGP 8.1.0-alpha09` or later due to [a bug](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#gradle-java-toolchains-support) in earlier version.
2. Remove all `compileOptions` blocks and `kotlinOptions.jvmTarget` in each of your module's `builde.gradle.kts`
3. In your root `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.kotlinExtension

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        kotlinExtension.jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
```

If it's still not working, hunt in your project and ensure there are no global overriding configurations something similar to below:

```kotlin
    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle ... >().configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```

Comment: Does this work if you have dependencies that require kotlin jvmTarget 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same incompatibility issues after adding kotlinx serialization dependencies while migrating to Ktor client from Retrofit and this was my solution.

1. Changed the JavaVersion.Version from 1.8 to 17 as shown below in the `build.gradle - module level`

   ```
   compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
   ```

   }
2. Change jvmTarget to 17

   `kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '17' }`
3. In the `build.gradle - project` level change the kotlin version to the following version or the latest version

   `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false`

Answer (score 1):

> JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

change to
JavaVersion.**VERSION_18**

> kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"

change to

```
kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "18"
```

Answer (score 1):

When I switch to Kotlin MultiPlatform get this error. for solve it , in bulid.gradle.kts(Module:shared) in kotlin tag :

```
kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }
```

and in android tag

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.mobiledemo"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
```

and in build.gradle.kts(Module:android), in android tag

```
android{
....
   compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there's a dependency mismatch.

I got a similar error when trying to add appwrite to my Flutter app. To be specific, flutter_web_auth_2 (a dependency that appwrite depended on) was throwing a similar error.

After hours of trial and error, downgrading my Kotlin version to match the flutter_web_auth_2's Kotlin version solved my issue.

It might be late for you, but I hope I helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
//    I also face the same issue and i have solved this issue... in //order to solve this you must have same version of java and kotline //running on your system.
    To solve this you have to add some code in android/gradle file --
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.8.0"
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
    
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

//Your app level build.gradle must be matched like--

```
    plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    }
    
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    
    android {
        namespace "com.example.aargus_shashi_1"
        compileSdkVersion 34
        buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
    
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.aargus_shashi_1"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion 19
            multiDexEnabled true
            targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
        dataBinding {
            enabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
        implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    
    }
   // Your gradle.wrapper.properties file present in //android/gradle/wrapper must be like-
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
    
    
  //  this error is caused by mismatch of the version which could //be usually happen when you integrate old library fucntion or code //into your new project.

//follow me for more help-
gitHub- https://github.com/shashikantkaushik
Linkedin-- https://in.linkedin.com/in/shashi-kant-kaushik
```

Answer (score -1):

I've the same error... but error starts when I added the "kotlin-kapt" plugin.

If you doesn't need use annotations, don't use it.
Also think to migrate to KSP. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html

But with the upgrade to Java 17 its enought.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34301628)

Answer (score -1):

try it:
**buid.gradle(Project)**

```
plugins {... id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.9.0" apply false}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got similar Issue, the following code snippet solved my problem though

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was very similar to the other ones but due to it being a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Project, I had to add the Source and Target Compatibility to both the androidApp and the shared module in the Project Structure window.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can set it up in `build.gradle(:app)` file if the above answers do not work. It works for me.

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.class){
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was also facing this error but solved it by spending too much time. it's very easy by just little bit change inside (android->gradle-> gradle_wrapper.properties) distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
just upgrade or downgrade accordingly