# Kotlin-based Android system administrator app: jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

This is the error I have been facing since yesterday:

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

[image]

And when I change my Java version to 17 then this is showing me:

> error: [Hilt]
> Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0

[image]

[Android Studio project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16abJh3zhUfqcPUTHFgHFc653-D1HnLMY/view?usp=sharing)

I have tried everything, but nothing makes it a success.

Comment: so what i do now

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76590532/10099768
Mine was a Flutter issue, but may help Android-Kotlin users as well.

I now try avoiding using the latest dependencies unless I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the gradle JDK version

[image]

Comment: by which JDK version