# How can I create a SQLite database and use it between screens in Kotlin with Jetpack Compose (Error with starting the app)?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a simple app in Kotlin(Jetpack Compose) and I'm having trouble resolving an issue which occurs when running my app. From my personal understanding which is not that good, it seems to me that the functionality should be working as intended but I am still not sure if theres a problem in the code itself or dependencies. Based on the logcat it seems that the database im trying to declare in MainActivity is not recognized/created. I've tried to resolve the issue by playing with dependencies using ChatGPT but I've only come across even more errors to fix and this one was taking a while already. As soon as I try to run the app it crashes. If anyone knows how to resolve this I would be extremely grateful.

**DATABASE SCREEN**

```
@Composable fun DatabaseScreen( navController: NavController, sliderValue: Float, userRepository: UserRepository ) { var userCount by remember { mutableStateOf(0) } var resultText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    val startTime = System.nanoTime()

                    for (i in 0 until (sliderValue * sliderValue * 10).toInt()) {
                        val age = i % 17 + 1
                        userRepository.insertUser(User(age = age))
                    }

                    val endTime = System.nanoTime()
                    val duration = endTime - startTime

                    // Update UI on the main thread
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        resultText = "Added users: ${(sliderValue * sliderValue * 10).toInt()} in $duration nanoseconds"
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

**DATABASE CLASSES AND FUNCTIONS**

```
 @Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val age: Int
)

@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}

@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User>

    @Query("DELETE FROM user")
    suspend fun clearDatabase()
}

class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User) {
        userDao.insertUser(user)
    }

    suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User> {
        return userDao.getAllUsers()
    }

    suspend fun clearDatabase() {
        userDao.clearDatabase()
    }
}
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val database = Room.databaseBuilder(
                applicationContext,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "my_database"
            ).build()


            val userRepository = UserRepository(database.userDao())
            setContent {
                var navController = rememberNavController()

                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "mainScreen") {
                    composable("mainScreen") { MyApp(navController) }
                    composable("Screen0") {
                        UIScreen(navController, 5f)
                    }
                    composable("Screen1") {
                        AnimationScreen(navController, 5f)
                    }
                    composable("Screen2") {
                        ArithmeticLogicalScreen(navController, 4f)
                    }
                    composable("Screen3") {
                        DatabaseScreen(navController, 5f,userRepository)
                    }
                    composable("Screen4") {
                        FeaturesScreen(navController, 5f)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**LOGCAT**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jurajappjetpack, PID: 9583
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jurajappjetpack/com.example.jurajappjetpack.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.jurajappjetpack.MainActivity.AppDatabase. MainActivity_AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.jurajappjetpack.MainActivity.AppDatabase. MainActivity_AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1357)
at com.example.jurajappjetpack.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:125)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

**BUILD.GRADLE PROJECT LEVEL**

```
plugins { id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
 id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false }
```

**BUILD.GRADLE MODULE LEVEL**

```
plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
```

}

```
android {
namespace = "com.example.jurajappjetpack"
compileSdk = 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.jurajappjetpack"
    minSdk = 28
    targetSdk = 33
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0")
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0")
implementation("androidx.compose.animation:animation-core")
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0")
implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.1")
implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0")
implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0")
implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.1.0-beta01")
implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.1.0-beta01")
implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add kapt plugin to the module build gradle e.g. (for all 3 plugins) :-

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Then change `annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")` to be

```
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2'
```

The annotationProcessor is for processing java kapt or ksp are for Kotlin. It is the processor that generates the Java code hence why code does not exist.

Comment: Thank you sir, ChatGPT also advised me to use this but it never told me to change annotationProcessor to kapt line but rather told me to just add it. Now that I actually knew this was the right path I stumbled upon a new error which was fixed by following this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480173/android-studio-build-error-compiledebugjavawithjavac-task-current-target-it-1