# Android Studio build error - compileDebugJavaWithJavac task (current target is 1.8) and compileDebugKotlin task (current target is 17) f

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I am working on an app it was working fine until i upgraded the gradle version now this is the error. I also tried changing the version to 17 but it doesn't seems to work and also changed the java version for gradle in setting android studio to 17.

```
Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' 
task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java 
version.
```

This is my buld.gradle file. Here i changed according to the error.

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.roam1.esim"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.sim"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

Comment: Did you change the Java version inside File->Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle?

Comment: I changed it to 17 there 'jbr 17'

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480173/android-studio-build-error-compiledebugjavawithjavac-task-current-target-it-1) help?

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused because you are trying to use Java 17 instead of Java 8.

In your `build.gradle`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Check also:

`Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Gradle`

and check if `Gradle JDK` is set to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

in your bulid.gradle update following

```css
//project level
 id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false

//app level
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.3'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on the project name and then click 'Open Module Settings'

Change the Gradle JDK to 17

[image]